# Why is the last part of this url not empty with ASP.NET webforms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, menu

Why is the last part of this url not empty?
When I visit my website, default.aspx automaticly loads but doesn't appear in the url. I use the url to highlight the menu on my website, so this doesn't work when you first visit the website.

This is the code how I make menu-items:

```
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();

// Get last part of the URL
string path = url.Split('/').Last();

if (path == menuPath || ((path == "default.aspx" && i==0) || (path == "" && i==0 )))
    panel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<a class='active' href='/" + menuPath + "'>"));
else
    panel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<a href='/" + menuPath + "'>"));
```

You would think that if the url is: http://example.com/ that the path variable will be "" and then it should give the class active right? Right now this doesn't work and I have no idea why.

**Make sure that the url is lowercase if you have this issue! Credits of this suggestion go to Ron C**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri` contains the full absolute url even including the protocol.  So if you hover over it in the debugger you will see that it contains "http://example.com/default.aspx" when you access example.com/ in your browser.

You will need to update your code to accommodate this or select a different `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url` property to use.  You can inspect all the properties available by hovering over that var in the debugger and expanding the little triangle to see all it's properties.

Comment: I changed it to your suggestion, published and uploaded it again however it didn't solve issue, unfortunately. It does work when debugging it locally but on the server it doesn't.

Comment: That's may be because the domain name is different in dev (i.e. localhost) then on the server.  If you post your updated code I can review it for you.

Comment: No worries, you don't need to send me your domain name.  The issue is that if you want the code to work on dev and production then it needs to not use url info that contains the host domain.  Which both your original choice and your new choice do.  Try using `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery` instead.  Again, you can run your code in the debugger to see the actual value being placed in your string from this property.

Comment: Sorry my last comment may not be your issue. I hadn't noticed `string path = url.Split('/').Last();` in your code which will get you just the last segment of the path which solves the domain issue I mentioned.  I think your issue may be how you are setting i.  Where is i set?  What's it's value when you hit the block of code you posted?

Comment: I posted my full menu class in the question.

Comment: It's odd that it doesn't work for sure.  If it's working on dev but not on production I'd output the value of url into page in the footer or somewhere so I could see exactly what it's getting set to in production.  That may provide the insight needed to fix the bug.

Comment: Wow :P
Thanks for that suggestion, the problem was that on production the variable path was "Default.aspx" so it would never match "default.aspx". So I added a .tolower() and now it works.

Comment: Awesome.  There is never any substitute for seeing exactly what the machine sees.  Have a good one.